# Convert state array values into key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

I have a state object array. I want to convert the values inside the array into a key-value pair

So, my state looks like this:

```
0: {emp_code: "a001", company_code: "company_a", name: "abx", details: Array(3), details_dtypes: Array(3)}
1: {emp_code: "b002", company_code: "company_b", name: "xbz ", details: Array(2), details_dtypes: Array(2)}
//and so on adding other values to the array
```

I want to convert the emp-code and company_code into a key-value pair and display like a JSON object; 
So the JSON output looks something like this:

```
{
emp_and_company:
{
  "company_a" : ["a001","a002"],
  "company_b" : ["b002","b003"]
}
}
```

So I just want to make the company_code as the key and values as the emp_code

Comment: from where you are getting `a002` and `b003`?

Comment: @brk from // and so on comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in a concise manner via [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [{ emp_code: "a001", company_code: "company_a", name: "abx", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "b002", company_code: "company_b", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "a002", company_code: "company_a", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "b003", company_code: "company_b", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] } ]

let result = data.reduce((r,c) => 
  (r[c.company_code] = [...(r[c.company_code] || []), c.emp_code]) && r, {})

console.log(result)
```

Here is a more readable version:

```js
const data = [{ emp_code: "a001", company_code: "company_a", name: "abx", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "b002", company_code: "company_b", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "a002", company_code: "company_a", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }, { emp_code: "b003", company_code: "company_b", name: "xbz ", details: [], details_dtypes: [] }]

let result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.company_code] = [...(acc[obj.company_code] || []), obj.emp_code]
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your answer seems correct, but it is giving me error: "data.reduce is not a function". I have used your code inside a function which is called on the click of a button; and I have saved data like this:  const data = JSON.stringify(this.state.company_data);

Comment: But `JSON.stringify` would return a string and you need an array to use `Array.reduce`. It should give you "data.reduce is not a function".

Comment: Oh it see! I now tried storing the state of the component in the data but it returns an undefined array